# Regular expression: same character 3 times

Tags: php, regex

I want a regular expression (in php) to this (same character 3 times):

```
aa => false
aaa => true
baaa => true
aaab => true
aaaaaab => true
baaab => true
babababa => false
```

For any character, not only 'a' and 'b'.

Comment: Including control characters?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [back-references](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) within a regex

```
/(.)\1\1/
```

Comment: The correct link to backreferences is [this](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html)

Answer (score 17):

Use this regular expression:

```
(.)\1{2}
```

Answer (score 3):

This will do the job :

```
/(.)\1\1/
```