# match the same unknown character multiple times

Tags: regex

I have a regex problem I can't seem to solve. I actually don't know if regex can do this, but I need to match a range of characters n times at the end of a pattern.
eg. blahblah[A-Z]{n}
The problem is whatever character matches the ending range need to be all the same.

For example, I want to match

- blahblahAAAAA
- blahblahEEEEE
- blahblahQQQQQ

but not

- blahblahADFES
- blahblahZYYYY

Is there some regex pattern that can do this?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147810/regular-expression-same-character-3-times

Answer (score 33):

You can use this pattern: `blahblah([A-Z])\1+`

The `\1` is a back-reference to the first capture group, in this case `([A-Z])`. And the `+` will match that character one or more times. To limit it you can replace the `+` with a specific number of repetitions using `{n}`, such as `\1{3}` which will match it three times.

If you need the entire string to match then be sure to prefix with `^` and end with `$`, respectively, so that the pattern becomes `^blahblah([A-Z])\1+$`

You can read more about [back-references here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

Answer (score 3):

In most regex implementations, you can accomplish this by referencing a capture group in your regex.  For your example, you can use the following to match the same uppercase character five times:

```
blahblah([A-Z])\1{4}
```

Note that to match the regex `n` times, you need to use `\1{n-1}` since one match will come from the capture group.

Answer (score 2):

`blahblah(.)\1*\b` should work in nearly all language flavors. `(.)` captures one of anything, then `\1*` matches that (the first match) any number of times.

Answer (score 0):

blahblah([A-Z]|[a-z])\1+
This should help.

Comment: Why are you using a non capture group? It's useless here.

Comment: Corrected. Thanks.

Comment: `[A-Z]|[a-z]` is a verbose expression.   It is more simply written as `[A-Za-z]` _if_ case insensitive matching is necessary.