# Use regex to match string in given condition

Tags: c#, regex, string-matching

### [Edit] Note:

Shortest regex is the main question, not about back-reference.

---

### Requirement:

Use shortest regex to match all string in following format:

```
<two digits><connect char><three digits><connect char><four digits>
```

For easy reading:

```
<two digits>
<connect char>
<three digits>
<connect char>
<four digits>
```

### Conditions:

- Match whole string, given that input string is single line.
- Connect char may both omit, or are any of `[-./ ]` (not include `[]`).
- Two connect char **must be the same** in each matched string.
- **Shortest** is important, performance is not important.

### Example

Some valid string:

```
55.635.8828
72/683/1582
86 942 7682
581827998      // Both connect chars is omit
```

Some invalid string:

```
56.855/9856     // Two connect chars are different.
56 4559428      // Same as above
```

This short regex will match all valid string:

```
^\d{2}[-./ ]?\d{3}[-./ ]?\d{4}$
```

But it also match invalid ones:

```
52-355/9984
```

This regex will match all correct string, but quite long. I break it to multi line for easy reading:

```
^(\d{2}-?\d{3}-?\d{4})|
(\d{2}\.?\d{3}\.?\d{4})|
(\d{2}/?\d{3}/?\d{4})|
(\d{2} ?\d{3} ?\d{4})$
```

Can you suggest me a shorter regex that meet the requirement?

Comment: `\A\d{2}([-./ ]?)\d{3}\1\d{4}\z`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [match the same unknown character multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11460397/match-the-same-unknown-character-multiple-times)

Comment: @Rawing: I also ask for shortest regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may capture the separator and use a backreference instead of repeating the pattern

```
^\d\d([-./ ]?)\d{3}\1\d{4}$
     ^       ^     ^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rJ5BUB/3)

In C#:

```
var isValid = Regex.IsMatch(s, @"^\d\d([-./ ]?)\d{3}\1\d{4}$");
```

Pass the `RegexOptions.ECMAScript` option to the regex compiler if you only want to match ASCII digits with `\d` (that, by default in .NET regex, matches [all Unicode digits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16621778/3832970)).

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\d\d` - any 2 digits
- `([-./ ]?)` - Group 1 capturing 1 or 0 `-`, `.`, `/` or space
- `\d{3}` - any 3 digits
- `\1` - the same value as captured in Group 1
- `\d{4}` - any 4 digits
- `$` - end of string (or you might want to use `\z` to ensure the exact end of the string, but it is not necessary in the majority of cases).

Comment: If *shortest* is really a priority, then `\d\d` is shorter than `\d{2}`

Comment: Look great! I don't know there have a feature `\1` to match backreference

Comment: @BurnsBA True, `\d\d` is one char shorter than `\d{2}`. Thanks for noticing.