# Regex to match three or more of the same char regardless of its position

Tags: javascript, php, regex

Looking for a regular expression in `PHP` or `javaScript` that return true if 3 or more of the same characters (regardless of its 'position') are found:

```
    "q6dqaqb" -> return true
    "qyakc6m" -> return false
    "jjfffua" -> return true
    "--rr4-c" -> return true
    "-qsev-m" -> return false
```

I have tried to the best of my ability to search for a solution like this

([Regular expression: same character 3 times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147810/regular-expression-same-character-3-times))

but this does not fit the requirement.

Edit:Thank you all for the swift reply. The PHP solution is awesome too.

Based on the answers, What is the difference between these regex:

```
(.)(?=.*\1.*\1)

.*(.).*\1.*\1.*

(?=.*(.).*\1.*\1)
```

Sorry, I can't live with myself until I understand what it means.

Comment: [`([\w-])([\w-]*\1){2}`](https://regex101.com/r/OotOMU/1).

Comment: So you mean three of the same character, even if they are non-consecutive? (Edit: If so, someone already beat me to the answer for that below.)

Comment: `.*(.).*\1.*\1.*` demo: https://regex101.com/r/G2QtLR/1

Answer (score 1):

Using lookahead to find the first of three:

```
/(.)(?=.*\1.*\1)/
```

Answer (score 1):

This expression

```
(?=.*(.).*\1.*\1)
```

might likely ensure that and to get the entire string, we can expand it to:

```
^(?=.*(.).*\1.*\1).*$
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6AoiYC/1/)

#### Test

```
$re = '/^(?=.*(.).*\1.*\1).*$/m';
$str = 'q6dqaqb
qyakc6m
jjfffua
--rr4-c
-qsev-m
';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

var_dump($matches);
```

#### Output

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "q6dqaqb"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "q"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "jjfffua"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "f"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "--rr4-c"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "-"
  }
}
```

```js
const regex = /^(?=.*(.).*\1.*\1).*$/gm;
const str = `q6dqaqb
qyakc6m
jjfffua
--rr4-c
-qsev-m
`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this `/(.).*\1.*\1/`.

Demo:

```js
var regex = /(.).*\1.*\1/;

console.log(regex.test("q6dqaqb"))
console.log(regex.test("qyakc6m"))
console.log(regex.test("jjfffua"))
console.log(regex.test("--rr4-c"))
console.log(regex.test("-qsev-m"))
```